# how do i add From in your php email

Tags: php, email

i am trying to add from that shows a email i enter but it shows up with the email the server i use CGI-Mailer i have googled this and have not found a way that works this is my code.

```
<?php
$to = "a@email.com";
$subject = "Test mail HTML";

$headers = "From: a@email.com" . "\n";
$headers = "Reply-To: a@email.com" . "\n";
$headers = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion() . "\n";
$headers = "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\n";

$message = 'a message';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

echo "Mail Sent to: $to";
?>
```

this all works other than showing up as a different email

thanks for any help!

Comment: there is a manual on this. Btw; this is a typo issue. Only the last header gets read and overwrites all previous header declarations.

Comment: what do i do to get all the headers to get read?

Comment: Visit https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and compare what you have with their examples and you'll get your answer.

Comment: i have just looked and noticed i forgot to put the .=

Comment: There you go ;-) glad to see you got it.

Comment: You're welcome, *cheers*